# "Equidecomposable": informal meaning

Tags: measure-theory, terminology, definition

I am having trouble understanding the definition of the term "equidecomposable".

Is it like two sets are split into many sets and then these many sets can be joined together to make either of the two original sets?

I dont understand.

Comment: I suppose this in context of the Banach-Tarski paradox?

Comment: Yes please help explain what it means.

Comment: @Math1000 This is my further understanding. Please say if it is correct or not: We have two polygons $A$ and $B$ which are equidecomposable if it is possible to decompose one of them, say $A$, into a finite number of pieces which can then be rearranged to form the second polygon $B$. These two polygons have equal areas, i.e they are congruent.